# The inclusion $\bigcap aM_n\subset a\bigcap M_n$ for descending chains of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with one, let 
$$
M=M_0>M_1>\cdots
$$ 
be a descending chain of finitely generated $A$-modules, and let $a$ be in $A$.

> Does the inclusion $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}aM_n\subset a\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}M_n\right)$$ always hold?

Here of course "$\subset$" means "is a not necessarily proper subset of".

---

Let us show that the answer is Yes if $A$ is a principal ideal domain.

We can assume $a\ne0$.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of elements of $M$ such that $ax_n=ax_0$ for all $n$.

It suffices to find an element $x$ in the intersection $I$ of the $M_n$ such that $ax=ax_0$.

We have $M_n=T_n\oplus F_n$, with $T_n$ torsion and $F_n$ free. The $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ forming a weakly decreasing sequence of artinian modules, we can assume $T_n=T\subset I$ for all $n$, and it suffices to prove $x_0\in I$.

Writing $x_n=t_n+f_n$ (obvious notation), it is enough to verify $f_0\in I$.

Our equation $ax_n=ax_0$ becomes the system 
$$
at_n=at_0,\quad af_n=af_0.
$$ 
This implies $f_0\in  f_n+T\subset M_n$ for all $n$, and thus $f_0\in I$, as was to be shown.

Comment: See Example 2.4 [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/66-1/pjm-v66-n1-p03-p.pdf).

Comment: @user26857 - Yes, I think it answers the question. Thanks a lot for this very interesting comment! If you prefer not to upgrade your comment to an answer, I'll do it in the community wiki mode (if you don't mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No.

As pointed out by user26857 in a comment, a counterexample is given by Example 2.4 in

Anderson, D., Matijevic, J., and Nichols, W. (1976). [The Krull intersection theorem. II](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/66-1/p03.xhtml). Pacific Journal of Mathematics, 66(1), 15-22.

Let $K$ be a field and let $A$ be the commutative unital $K$-algebra generated by the symbols $a,x,y_1,y_2,\dots$ subject to the relations 
$$
x=ay_1=a^2y_2=a^3y_3=\cdots
$$ 
We have
$$
x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\ (a)^n=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\ a\ (a)^n,\quad x\notin a\,\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\ (a)^n,
$$ 
so that we get our counterexample by setting $M:=A$ and $M_n:=(a)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a noetherian counterexample:

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ the commutative $K$-algebra with one generated by the symbols $a$ and $b$ subject to the relations $ab^2=ab$ and $a^2=0$.

We clearly have $ab=ab^2=ab^3=\cdots$

The set 
$$
\{a,ab\}\cup\{b^n\ |\ n\ge0\}
$$ 
is a $K$-basis of $A$. This implies in particular
$$
A=K[b]\oplus Ka\oplus Kab,
$$ 
and we get 
$$
a\ \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\ (b^n)=a\,(ab)=(0),
$$ 
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\ a\,(b^n)=(ab)\ne(0).
$$ 
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3435407/660) shows that any counterexample which is a $K$-algebra must have at least two generators.